# Meteor: one backend - multiple different front-ends 2x web and 1x mobile

Tags: android, mobile, meteor

I want one meteor server that can serve multiple different front-ends:

- Simple Web App
- Admin Web App
- Mobile App

Each app has almost completely different HTML.  Having all 3 packaged together isn't a blocker for the Admin and Mobile apps, but it is a blocker if the Simple Web app gets bloated with code from the other two.

I don't understand enough about the Meteor build process to work out a solution.  I could really use some help with best practices

Some things I've tried:

1. Separate apps -> separate repos.  I got stuck trying to point the Mobile App at the Simple App repo.
2. Separate apps -> same repo.  Not sure how to organize this.  Meteor seems pretty sure everything is one app
3. One App -> One repo.  App detects mobile and uses different template?  [device-detection](https://github.com/mystor/meteor-device-detection) looks abandoned (asked for a PR for iron-router, but never merged it).

Any suggestions?  If your Meteor site's mobile app is almost completely different than its web app, how do you manage it?

Comment: One approach would be 3 apps, one db but that implies near zero code re-use and a maintenance nightmare. I suspect you would want common server and probably lib code but distinct client code.

Comment: I can even imagine there's a bit of code (like: layout) that is iOS or Android specific, so I'd might even like some mobile folder to have more specific subfolders.

Comment: See the roadmap: [Incremental loading](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading). And to be prepared to split a single huge project in multiple projects without too much repeated code, I'm looking into using "local smart packages": [Meteor project structure — the way forward](http://www.matb33.me/2013/09/05/meteor-project-structure.html) and [Configuration for multiple clients](https://forums.meteor.com/t/configuration-for-multiple-clients/8959). Some [are using symbolic links or `PACKAGE_DIRS`](https://forums.meteor.com/t/building-multiple-apps-from-the-same-source/8822).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using symlinks and it's been successful.  Here's how my git repo looks (more or less):

```
/all
/all/public
/all/client
/all/server

/app1/client
/app1/client/shared -> symlink to ../../all/client
/app1/server/shared -> symlink to ../../all/server
/app1/public        -> symlink to ../all/public

/app1/client
/app1/client/shared -> symlink to ../../all/client
/app1/server/shared -> symlink to ../../all/server
/app1/public        -> symlink to ../all/public
```

Cheers!